# Appirater not available in AppDelegate

Tags: appirater

I have installed Appirater with Cocoapods however I can't see the class in AppDelegate for some reason. `

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // set up Appirater
    Appirater.setAppId("...") //DOES NOT RECOGNISE APPIRATER
}
```

pod file looks like

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
target 'myapp' do
   use_frameworks!
pod 'Appirater'
end
```

I have used use_frameworks in pod file so I don't think I need a bridging header file. Any help to get this working much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You're using frameworks, which means to need to import the framework just like you would any other framework:

`import Appirater`

Comment: @richc, I actually struggled with that for a while when I was importing another framework recently, so just learned this.